# Can an improper integral with infinity singularity converge for any integrand?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have an integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$, where $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \infty$ and $\forall x \geq 0: f(x)>0$. Is there any $f(x)$ that fulfills these requirements such that the integral converges? If not, how can you prove it does not exist?

Comment: $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac1{\sqrt x}, & x\in(0,1),\\ \frac1{x^2}, & x\in[1,\infty)\end{cases}.$$

Comment: @Feng Thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: It’s instructive to consider the case of $f(x) = x^{-a}, a>0$, for $x\in [0,1]$ and (say) $f(x) = 0$ for $x>1$. Its integral converges provided $a<1$. You can also consider modifications, like $f(x) = x^{-a}\ln^b x$, etc.